# Fancybox sometimes redirects current page instead of loading in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox for a search function, which I've been using for some time. Recently I updated to fancybox 2.0. Since I upgraded, every once in a while one of my fancyboxes loads in the current window instead of the iframe. Here's the applicable code:

```
<a href="../rets/search.aspx" class="mlsSearch">Search</a>
```

And fancybox js

```
$("a.mlsSearch").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'type': 'iframe',
    'scrolling': 'auto',
    'centerOnScroll': false
});
```

Any idea as to what could be causing this problem? I can't seem to figure out why this one is breaking and the rest, with similar code, are working fine.

Comment: Any error output via firebug console?

Comment: @SG86 nope -- other than a failed GET request to a site looking for `replace.js`. I don't think it's fancybox related. I wish I knew exactly what it were, but I didn't write this code, I inherited it.

Comment: Your link does not have a class with the name or "mlsSearch".

Comment: @AlexMendez Sorry, that was a copying error. In the real code it's in there

Comment: As SG86 said, this is usually a script error. The Firebug console might not show it, as it gets reset when the new page loads. Try the web developer error console (`Ctrl+Shift+J` on Windows).

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the fancybox's API options too? In v2.x they are new and NOT compatible with previous versions. For instance `hideOnContentClick` doesn't exist in v2.x but `closeClick` should be used instead. Check the proper [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the right options.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the reason was that if you use Fancybox in mode of iFrame and want to force content like this:

```
<span onclick="$.fancybox({content:'Hello',type:'iframe'});">Iframe</span>
```

... then the content value has to be valid URL that is loaded into iFrame. You probably can't specify HTML code for iFrame. Instead URL "Hello" will be searched.

This works fine:

```
<span onclick="$.fancybox({content:'Hello'});">Iframe</span>
```